# Max Value based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with multiple columns that contains both month and year. I'm trying to identify based on column1,column2 what is the greatest month and year.

I have a DDL for a test table as such.

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
   (    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
    "YEAR" NUMBER, 
    "MONTH" NUMBER
   );
```

This is the data in the example table.

```
REM INSERTING into TEST
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEST (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,YEAR,MONTH) values ('A','A',11,4);
Insert into TEST (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,YEAR,MONTH) values ('A','A',14,3);
Insert into TEST (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,YEAR,MONTH) values ('A','A',11,5);
Insert into TEST (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,YEAR,MONTH) values ('A','A',14,1);
```

I want to get the record with the max month and year. When I attempt to retrieve the record using this query

```
 SELECT t.COLUMN1, t.COLUMN2, max(t.YEAR), max(t.MONTH) 
 FROM TEST t 
 group by COLUMN1, COLUMN2;
```

I get this results

[image]

It appears to me that it is separating the max year and max month independently of the other columns.
The expected result should be 
[image]

how can I get down to the appropriate results?
I have tried several self-joins to no avail.

Comment: May I ask why you are storing the month and year in separate columns?

Comment: @Tim ERP solution, not my design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use Oracle's built-in [`LAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) (or [`FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm)) with `MAX` like this:

```
SELECT t.COLUMN1,
  t.COLUMN2,
  MAX(t.YEAR),
  MAX(t.MONTH) keep (dense_rank last ORDER BY YEAR nulls first) MONTH
FROM TEST t
GROUP BY COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2;
```

It will find the max of month in latest year only.

Comment: Thank you my friend that is is brilliant.

Comment: @Miguel - Often the "first' `MAX` (like the `MAX` by year in this example) is unique, and using `MAX(...)` with the `FIRST/LAST` function is not really needed - it picks up the `MAX` from a set of just one value. However Oracle can't know that at parse time (without seeing all the data), so it still requires an aggregate function (on month, in this case). This example is an excellent illustration of the **full** power of `FIRST/LAST`, where the `MAX` used with `keep(dense_rank first/last order by...)` is actually fully utilized.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the explanation. It was quite eye-opening for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate somehow both values, calculate max, and then split them. In case of year and month, you can calculate months since some epoch:

```
select column1, column2,
       trunc(max(year*12+month-1)/12) year,
       mod  (max(year*12+month-1),12)+1 month
  from test
 group by column1, column2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct column1, column2, year, max(month) over(partition by column1, column2, year) mxmnth
from ir_wip.test  tbl2
where year=(select  max(year) from ir_wip.test  tbl where tbl.column1=tbl2.column1 and tbl.column2=tbl2.column2)
```

Comment: Hi, please include an explanation (even code comments are better than nothing).

Comment: In a partition you can control the aggregate fields independently, unlike grouping. 
 However, Dense rank works nicely.  The only value to partition in this particularly easy example (which may not be representative) is that it is obvious without notes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have additional information to add.

Comment: Also, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers). Explaining your code increases the value of your post in the long term. Help others read your code and, in return, increase your chances of getting upvoted.